# How to dynamically name a variable

Tags: c#, sql, string

I would like to dynamically set string variables taken from a database.
So instead of setting each variable manually as bellow

```cs
String XXX = "123";
String YYY = "456";
String ZZZ = "789";
```

I would like to set the variables dynamical as follows

Table: DefualtValues

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 |
| YYY | 456 |
| ZZZ | 789 |

```cs
myDBConnection.Open();
string GetDefualtValuesSQL = "SELECT * FROM DefualtValues";
SQLCommand = new MySqlCommand(GetDefualtValuesSQL, myDBConnection);
dbReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (dbReader.Read())
{
   String dbReader.GetString(0)= dbReader.GetString(1);     
}

myDBConnection.Close();

Console.WriteLine(XXX);
/// Should output 123
```

Comment: This is very clearly an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the use case for this? I think you might be looking for a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0), but that's just speculation. Please explain what you're actually trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: Is there a reason they have to be in declared variables?  Can you simply use a `Dictionary<string, string>` and put the `ID` in the key and the `Value` in the value?

Comment: Even if there was a way to do that, it would be a bad idea. What if someone manages to introduce a name like `Console` into the database? Such functionality did exist in a few scripting languages, specifically for CGI use, but it got very much deprecated or removed from these languages. As the others say, in doubt, use a dictionary, or a structured way to save your data.

Comment: You also may be interested in the `DataTable` object see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-7.0

Comment: You could go the dynamic, or an Anon Type but the DataTable is a perfect fit here.

Comment: The goal is to have responses that are not hard coded in. That way I can change the text without having to recompile the whole thing. I will look into using a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people in the comments mentioned, you can go for something like this:

```
myDBConnection.Open();
string GetDefualtValuesSQL = "SELECT * FROM DefualtValues";
SQLCommand = new MySqlCommand(GetDefualtValuesSQL, myDBConnection);
dbReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

IDictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

while (dbReader.Read())
{
    result.Add(dbReader.GetString(0), dbReader.GetString(1));
}

myDBConnection.Close();

Console.WriteLine(result["XXX"]);
/// Should output 123
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thank-you.